# pass parameter using struts

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have my action like this :

```
<package name="redirect" namespace="/go" extends="default">
    <action name="life" class ="baseAction">
        <result>forward.jsp?Id=life</result>
    </action>

    <action name="car" class ="baseAction">
        <result>forward.jsp?Id=car</result>
    </action>

    <action name="health" class ="baseAction">
        <result>forward.jsp?Id=health</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I want to set the id in struts and access it in the jsp file. I have a getter method and setter method for id in BaseAction.java. But the id is not getting set. How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are using Struts2 you should not add param in struts.xml

Comment: @Soorapadman How can I set the value then?

Comment: can you edit your question and post all related  code then only i can sorted out?

Comment: Basically i have a forward.jsp which checks the value of Id and performs some task. Now i want, if the link is /go/life.html, then it should execute the code for "life". If the link is /go/car.html, then it should execute the code for "car". else for health. when the users clicks on the /go/life.html, i want id to have "life"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this code:

```
<action name="life" class="baseAction">
    <param name="id">life</param>
    <result>forward.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i need. :) :)